# How did this character die in "War for the Planet of the Apes"?

Tags: planet-of-the-apes, planet-of-the-apes-2011, war-for-the-planet-of-the-apes

Can someone explain

> Caesar's death? It doesn't make any sense to me how Caesar died from his arrow wound only after traveling across mountains and finally reaching his destination.

Did it become infected or something? Seems very odd.

Comment: https://healthcare.utah.edu/the-scope/shows.php?shows=0_81kwlsx2 - he most likely had a slow, inoperable bleed and simply died of blood loss

Comment: Not to mention his old age probably played a factor.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks don't think Caesar was very old. He can't have been older than 25 which is about 50 in human years.

Comment: [Caesar was 20 when he died](http://planetoftheapes.wikia.com/wiki/Caesar_(CE)), but he was also a genetically mutated veteran of two wars who'd already survived being shot previously. Getting shot with an arrow and seeking no help with the wound would kill a *normal* person, let alone one with his medical history.

Answer (score 3):

**Blood loss and internal bleeding.**

> The wound from Preacher’s crossbow bolt had never had a chance to
> truly heal. Caesar suspected that he needed surgery, as he had after
> Koba had shot him years ago, but human surgeons like Ellie were in
> short supply these days, especially if you were an ape. Caesar was not
> surprised that the climb had torn open the wound again. The hot blood
> streaming from his side showed no sign of stopping, and he had little
> doubt that he was bleeding inside as well.
>
> <sub><sup>[War for the Planet of the Apes: Official Movie Novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/34437947-war-for-the-planet-of-the-apes)</sup></sub>